# Binding LongListSelector to nested ObserverCollection that's updated asynchronously (using WebClient)

Tags: c#, silverlight, observablecollection, silverlight-toolkit, longlistselector

I have a `LongListSelector` in a Windows Phone Silverlight project, that is bound to a nested `ObservableCollection`.

In order to get the grouping working and updating automatically, I'm using a custom group class that extends `ObservableCollection`.

My class structure looks like this:

Main.xaml.cs:

```
ObservableCollection<Group<MyViewModel>> _groups;
```

Group.cs:

```
Group<T> : ObservableCollection<T> {...}
```

I'm populating the groups asynchronously, using a `WebClient`:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.OpenReadCompleted += (sender, obj) {
    // parse the response here, get list of MyModels
    ...

    foreach (var model in models)
    {
        var group = _groups.SingleOrDefault(g => g.Key == model.Key);
        if (group == null)
        {
            group = new Group<MyModel> { Key = model.Key };
            _groups.Add(group);
        }

        group.Add(model);
    }
}
```

All this works fine, except for binding to the `LongListSelector`.
The first item gets added fine, but every subsequent item added to the groups list results in an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception.

I've tried handling the `CollectionChanged` event to add the items to the group, instead of on `ReadComplete`, but same result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add each item as it comes as a group.  You should get the entire data and group them and assign to the longlistselector. Groping on a incremental loaded data would not work good as a new item coming in might need to be added to an existing group.

Here is a good sample on the same to use on a flat list that is readily available and grouped and assigned to longlistselector

[How to display data in a grouped list in LongListSelector for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244365%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[Windows Phone Series – Jump Lists](http://rahulpnath.com/blog/windows-phone-series-jump-lists/)